# Django __istartswith does't work. Python 2.7, Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode

I am working with cyrillic text. There is parser written in python2.7 which saves strings from another site into database, which are saved as unicode to database `[u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b']`

type:

```
<type 'lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult'>
```

In templates it's shown as normal text (russian this case), but search  doesn't work. In this case using django filters(any)(and the relevant data is present)do not return by the normal key? Is it correct behaviour? What is the right solution?

Tired cyrillic letter, and the must be results by this search. The type of string is unicode, but find nothing among many result starting with the following letter, so something is wrong, but I can't understand why. And at the same time english search keys give relevant search result to english words, while russian do not.

```
 var = u'б'
 print(type(var))
 result = Event.objects.filter(title__istartswith= var)
```

EDIT:  actually simple exact filter works , but anything complex doesn't

EDIT: and title__contains also works. so I'll better rename the questions not to get beaten. but behaviour is pretty strange, sometimes it doesn't show anything thought exact same title is the key. why? and still in face I need start with functionality which doesn't work

Comment: Not so familiar with django but I would start by looking at what has been inserted into the db.

Comment: @AidanKane exactly what I printed at the top and the type

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. Which db are you using? What collation do you have set on the column / table? I'd be trying to log the query that django is running against the db.

Comment: @AidanKane postgres in production, litesql localt

Comment: @Kane actually simple exact filter works

Comment: you should use the same RDBMS for production and testing. Sqlite and postgres are very very different

Comment: I know, had some issue with local postgres( two installed, and there is some mess) so I just saved the time to fix crutial bugs

Comment: @e4c5 at least here not working behaviour is the same locally and in prod